# Check if working on databricks notebook or ont

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks

For some functions I need to split logic for databricks notebook with big cluster and for local machines. So is there a way to check, if R runs on databricks notebook. Like some tag in `Sys.info()` or something ?

Comment: You control the environment. Just a set a variable on submit, and check it from the application.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in `.Platform$GUI`. if it is equal to RStudio (in my case only RStudio) this is a local machine, in other cases databricks notebook

Comment: This will be true for linux as well, not only Databricks

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if (NROW(grep('DATABRICKS', names(Sys.getenv()))) > 0 ){
    print("We are on Databricks")}else{
    print("We are not on Databricks")}
```